# how to find file from blockName in HDFS hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

What's the easiest way to find file associated with a block in HDFS given a block Name/ID

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The long and painful way, assuming you have read access to all the files (and execute for the directories):

```
hadoop fsck / -files -blocks | grep blk_520275863902385418_1002 -B 20
```

Then scan back up from your block match to the previous file name:

```
/hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info 4 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
0. blk_520275863902385418_1002 len=4 repl=1
```

In this case blk_5202... is part of the `/hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info` file

Programmatically, these isn't an interface to the name node that allows you to search by block ID, but you could look into the source for the secondary name node and see how it consolidates the edits - then experiment on the saved output from the secondary name node (rather than risking working on the live name node file).

Good luck!

Comment: This may take longer time if you cast on a relatively large cluster. However this give you the block size and the full block identifier that includes which DataNode it resides.

Answer (score 18):

Not sure when this was introduced but you can do this

```
hdfs fsck -blockId <block_id>

hdfs fsck -blockId blk_1100790203
Connecting to namenode 
FSCK started by hdfs 

Block Id: blk_1100790203
Block belongs to: /tmp/1447685899336.txt
```

Comment: This works faster than Chris' answer. My HDFS version is 3.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: the suffix `.meta` is needed if using the blockId with generationStamp

```
$ hdfs fsck -blockId blk_1073823706_82968.meta
```

Option 2: use the blockId without generationStamp

```
$ hdfs fsck -blockId blk_1073823706
```