# How to find blockName to DataNode mapping in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a programatic interface to find out whether given a blockID it exists on which data node.
I.e. ability to read fsImage and return this info.

Answer (score 0):

One of the crude ways i know of is to look for a file with blockName in the dfs data dir.
This is however an O(n) solution and i am pretty sure there would be an O(1) solution to this.

Comment: if you want to add more information after question posted then you should update your question using Edit tag. so keep in mind this should be in question not as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [how to find file from blockName in HDFS hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881449/how-to-find-file-from-blockname-in-hdfs-hadoop), there is no public interface to the namenode which will allow you to lookup information froma block Id (only by file name).

You can look at opening the fsImage but this will only give you a mapping from block ID to filename as the actual locations (DataNodes) which host the blocks are not stored in this file - the data nodes treewalk their data directories and report to the NameNode what blocks thay have.

I guess if you could attach a debugger to the name node, you might be able to inspect the block map, but because there is no map from ID to filename, it's still going to be a O(n) operation